# Ruby, rubygems and rails conflict with stock Mac OS X Leopard files

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Ok guys, so I've been trying to install ruby on my mac for the past two days. What seems to be happening is that there's a conflict between the stock ruby, rubygems and rails from Mac OS X Snow Leopard and the ones I'm trying to install.

I'm using rvm to get the files, therefore I'm running `rvm install 1.9.2`. Installation seems to go normally, but when I run `ruby -v`, it shows me the old version (1.8.7). Same goes for rubygems. While rvm should installs it, when I run `gem -v`, old version is shown (1.3.5). \

This screenshot shows what I'm saying: http://cl.ly/2a3m1v0u331i272z2J22

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've installed RVM, you also need to tell you system that you want to use that version of Ruby. This is usually done via:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

However, when you open a new shell, it will revert back to the system default. If you want to set 1.9.2 as your default ruby, use:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

I suggest you look through the documentation a bit more to help you get the most out of RVM:

Basics: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/
Best Practices: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/

Comment: Thank you Dan, but that didn't help. Even when I do that, it still shows me version 1.8.7. Please see: http://cl.ly/0O370J113T1e2i3N3S3F

Very frustrating

Comment: Is there a reason you installed it for multi-user configuration, rather than in your own home directory? Also, did you follow the directions and add the RVM configuration to your profile?

Comment: rvm won't work at all if you didn't add it to your .bash_profile so seems like Dan did this.

Comment: Hi Dan, I was following a tutorial on how to set up the whole environment, and it instructed me to install is as root. I managed to solve the problem by adding rvm to my bash_profile. I just have one last issue though. If I run `rails -v` with my user, it returns version 3.0.1, but when I do that as root, it returns me an error. See: http://cl.ly/2A1V460r2n2v46322137

What might that be? Thanks again

Comment: The root user doesn't inherit the RVM configuration—namely GEM_PATH. That said, there's never any reason to be running `rails` as root.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

/usr/local/bin should be before /usr/bin.
If not so - change it in your /Users/Your_name/.bash_profile

Comment: Hi Anton, in fact my /usr/bin is before /usr/local/bin. What should I put into my .bash_profile in order to change that? Thanks.